# how to get parameterized type from certain class

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class as below

```
public class X<T> {
    Integer x1;
    T x2;
}
```

Is it possible to get the type of X by providing the class of certain T?
Some thing like below code.

```
public <T> Class<?> getType(Class<T> cls) {
    return X<cls>.class;
}
```

===================== news =======================

Thank you all for your answers. Let me explain more details of my question.

I just want to deserialize an Object of X. Let say T = Integer.

if use Gson, the code would be:

```
X x = new Gson().fromJson("{x1: 1, x2: 2}", new TypeToken<X<Integer>>(){}.getType());
```

but I don't want to write so long everytime. I am thinking if there is way can simplify the code to be as below:

```
X x = deserializeFunc("{x1: 1, x2: 2}", Integer.class);
```

Comment: : (  Actually my purpose is to deserialize an object of type X<T> using gson. And I don't want to pass the how class type of X<T> ..

Comment: If your issue is deserializing a class with Gson, you'd have better luck asking *that* question, rather than how to mangle the type system.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are "erased" at runtime, which means (among other things) that there's only one `Class` object for a given generic class. For example, the below prints `true`:

```
final List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println(stringList.getClass() == integerList.getClass());
```

So your question doesn't really make sense; your method has return-type `Class<?>`, so you obviously don't intend for the type argument to be available at compile-time; and `X.class` is just a single instance regardless of the type argument, so the type argument doesn't exist at runtime.

(But I'm not sure if that's a "yes" or a "no". I guess it depends on what you're trying to accomplish with this!)

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this sort of problem is to require the caller pass in the `Class` into the constructor. There are many examples of this (e.g. [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)), and your `X` class might look like:

```
public class X<T> {
  private final Class<T> clazz;
  // fields

  public X(Class<T> clazz, /* arguments... */) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    // set fields
  }

  public Class<T> getClass() {
    return clazz;
  }

  // ...
}
```

---

If your goal is to refer to the *generic* type (e.g. `X<T>` at runtime you'll need to use a different workaround. Gson offers exactly such a feature with [`TypeToken`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html), which allows you to specify a generic type at runtime. This is discussed in the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types), here's their example:

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<Foo<Bar>>() {}.getType();
gson.toJson(foo, fooType);

gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

Comment: I *think* you've misunderstood the question. OP wants to get `X` from `T`, not vice-versa. (Not my downvote.)

Comment: @shmosel I've expanded my answer to discuss Gson's `TypeToken`, which I believe is what OP is trying to get at.

Comment: So you're saying OP wants a type to represent a parameterized `X`. Not exactly what I understood, but you're probably right. Though he may want the parameter type to be dynamic, which I don't think is supported by Gson's `TypeToken` (as opposed to [Guava's](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#where-com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter-java.lang.Class-)).

Answer (score 0):

It is not.  The erasures that happen in java, don't allow for that to happen.  I less than ideal solution is to create a field of type Class on your class that you can then later look at:

```
public class X<T> {
    final Class<T> myType;
    Integer x1;
    T x2;
    public X(Class<T> myType) {
      this.myType = myType;
    }
}
```

then you could do x.myType to get the class of the generic type.